# Retrieval of image from different storage using WHILE in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Goodday! I just want to know if there is a possible trick for this kind of problem. I want to fetch the image of my rows in php, i have 3 categories hotel, restaurants and Places To Go and each category has different storage(folder) i already fetch the other necessary data but the image is really hard for me to do that can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thank you in advance :)

//Mysql statement to get the data

```
$query = "

SELECT hotel as name, province, address as address, image as image FROM hotel
        WHERE CONCAT(hotel,province,address) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'

       UNION ALL
      SELECT tourist_spot as name, province, address as address, image as image FROM users
        WHERE CONCAT(tourist_spot,province,address) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'

       UNION ALL
        SELECT restau_name as name, province, restau_address as address, image as image FROM restauu
       WHERE CONCAT(restau_name,province,restau_address) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'

";
```

[image: Sample output]

```html
<div class="col-md-4"  style="border-left: 3px solid #ff9800;">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
<div class="ResultContainer">
<div class="SearchResul1" style="float: left;">
 <?php 

if($valueToSearch = $row['hotel']){
echo "<img src='../hotel/upload/$row[image]' id='TouristImage'>";
}else if($valueToSearch = $row['tourist_spot']){
echo "<img src='../touristspotinformation/upload/$row[image]' id='TouristImage'>";
 }else if($valueToSearch = $row['restau_name']){
 echo "<img src='../ca/upload/$row[image]' id='TouristImage'>";
}
                                       
  ?>
</div>
<div style="width: 300px; float:left;">
<h3 style="font-size: 20px;"><p><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color: #333; font-family: candara;"><?php echo $row['name'];?></a></p></h3>
<span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span><label >Located at &nbsp;<?php echo $row['province']; ?></label><br>
</div>
<div class="SearchResul3" style="float:right;">
<?php echo "<a onclick='window.open(this.href); return false;' href='TourPackages_ViewDetails.php?id=".$row['id']."&packages_name=".$row['package_name']."&packages_image=".$row['image']."&packages_category=".$row['Category']."'><label id='Prices1'><h4>View Details</h4></label></a>"; ?>                                          </div>
</form>
 </div>
                                               
<div class="clearfix">
                                                        <div></div>
                                                        <div></div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have issue in `if` condition use `==` for comparison `=` is assignment operator

```
if($valueToSearch == $row['hotel']){
 echo "<img src='../hotel/upload/$row[image]' id='TouristImage'>";
}else if($valueToSearch == $row['tourist_spot']){
 echo "<img src='../touristspotinformation/upload/$row[image]' id='TouristImage'>";
 }else if($valueToSearch == $row['restau_name']){
 echo "<img src='../ca/upload/$row[image]' id='TouristImage'>";
}
```